# In Itunes Connect, submit the "ready to sale" build to Testflight again

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, testflight

I was wondering if it possible to submit expired build to Testflight (while in the activity > All builds I have multiple builds, in Testflight > Builds I don't have any to select from).

[image]
[image]

I need the testers to have the option to install the current production app (ready for sale), and then perform an "update" using the new build I will upload.

Is there a way to accomplish that? except for bumping the production version in xcode and submitting it again ( I tried to upload from the archive manager the same build again, but it failed, as the build already exists...).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The submitted, testable version will automatically become inactive for testing if the app is approved by Apple. You'd need to bump the version # by submitting a new version for people to test.

For example

1. Submitted version 1.2 for testing
2. Users download and test 1.2 with no problems
3. You now submit 1.2 for approval
4. Upon approval the app will become inactive for users until a new build is submitted and the version is higher than the currently approved version